# With set -e, exit status of command following ! is lost in an if block

Tags: bash

```
set -e
if ! some_command; then
  RET=$?
  if [[ $RET == 255 ]]; then
    ...do something handling...
  fi
fi
```

guess what happened? 
the `RET` will always be 0, regardless the `some_command` returns non-zero value.

Is this by design? I can not believe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As oguz ismail said, this is a result of `!` -- since it converts failure status to success, and there's only one possible success status (zero), it necessarily loses the specific failure code. But you can do the equivalent of this without using `!`:

```
set -e
some_command || {
  RET=$?
  if [[ $RET == 255 ]]; then
    ...do something handling...
  fi
}
```

Unlike the `PIPESTATUS` solution, this is portable to non-bash shells (it should work with any POSIX shell). (Although as oguz ismail pointed out, the `[[ ]]` conditional expression isn't portable -- the portable version would be `if [ "$RET" = 255 ]; then`.)

Comment: Using `case` may save you needing to save the value of `$?`: `case $? in 255) ... ;; esac`. The comparison made by `case` is done internally, rather than as a separate command which modifies the value of `$?`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is *by design* (and has nothing to do with `set -e`); `!` negates the exit status of pipeline it precedes. However, the exit statuses of pipeline components can be found in [`PIPESTATUS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-PIPESTATUS) variable, for example:

```
set -e
if ! some_command; then
  ret=$PIPESTATUS
  # do something with ret ...
fi
```

Proof of concept:

```
$ ! (exit 42)
$ echo $?,$PIPESTATUS
0,42
$
```